# Bounds on dependent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Consider this problem: You roll a dice *n* times. Let $ X_i $ be the number of times you see face $i$. Specifically, I am interested in $ E[ \max\limits_{i} X_i] $. In fact, I don't even need an exact answer but even *good* lower bound would suffice. The approach that I am taking for this problem is as follows:

By Hoeffding's Inequality, we can say for every face $i$,

$ Pr[ X_i > \mu + \lambda] \leq exp(- \frac{2 \lambda ^2}{n}) $

If we use $ \lambda = \sqrt{n/2} $, then $ Pr[ X_i > \mu + \lambda] \leq e^{-1}$.  By union bound I can even sum up these individual probabilities but as you can see, we get a trivial upper bound of $ \frac{6}{e} $ (for 6 faces) which doesn't really help. Also, I cannot use any other bound since the random variables $X_i$ are not independent.

I feel like I need to do something more sophisticated to get what I want but not sure where to start looking. I have got some random pointers on the internet but would like to request audience here for some more specific direction or if there are some well studied concepts involving these.

Comment: To me this is a wonderfully fresh and intriguing problem. So far, I have had no better success than you. I'm unclear whether you really want a lower or upper bound. In case it is of any interest, I focused on approximations and simulated the expectation (for my own orientation) with 5, 10, 20, and 50, rolls of a fair six-sided die, obtaining approximate means 2.14, 3.44, 5.79, and 12.1 At least this makes me skeptical of your upper bound. Doesn't it have to increase with n?

Comment: This is a classical textbook problem, usually asked to check that one understands conditionings in the gaussian setting... Note that $X_i^{(n)}=(n/6)+\sqrt{n/6}Y_i$ where $(Y_i)$ is asymptotically centered normal with common variance $5/6$ and common covariance $-1/6$, hence $Y_i=Z_i-\bar Z$ where $(Z_i)$ is standard normal. It follows that $$\lim\frac{E(\max X_i^{(n)})-(n/6)}{\sqrt{n/6}}=E(\max Z_i),$$ where $(Z_i)$ is i.i.d. centered normal with variance $1$. You should be able to compute the RHS  $E(\max Z_i)$.

Comment: @Did Thanks for you answer. I come from computer science background so there are lot of things I am not aware of but are you sure $ X_i^{(n)} = n/6 + \sqrt{n/6} Y_i$ holds when X_i are dependent variables? Can you please also suggest the right keywords so that I can learn more about this?

Comment: Yes I am sure, the difference with the i.i.d. setting you have in mind is that, here, the reduced random variables $Y_i$ are not independent. This explains the nonzero covariance terms and is dealt with by representing $(Y_i)$ as some linear transform of an independent family $(Z_i)$.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo I want lower bound for $ E[ \max\limits_{i} X_i] $. In the particular problem that I am facing right now, the number of faces to the die is another parameter (say $k$) . If I could say, $ Pr[ X_i < \mu + \lambda ] > \epsilon $, then the Pr that all $X_i$ are within this limit is at least $ \epsilon^k$ (If $X_i$ were independent). Hence, I would be able to say that the Pr that at least one face crosses the limit is sufficiently high.

The upper bound does not increase with $n$ because the parameter $\lambda$ is not constant.I think it captures the same idea as in your experiment.

Comment: @Did I tried bypassing this particular issue in the problem that I am solving but apparently I can't. Honestly, I have not understood a lot from your answer but clearly this is the way forward for me. I would hate to keep pestering you with questions, so it would be nice if you could point me to lecture notes/wiki pages (or even what these ideas are called) on this topic or the concepts that you have used to make this claim. I don't know what to search for to learn more about this and clearly there is a lot I need to understand here.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let me suggest instead to start from what I explained and to try to compute/estimate $E(\max Z_i)$ when $(Z_1,Z_2,\ldots,Z_6)$ is standard normal.